# How to run Ansible locally?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am using Ansible version 2.2.0.0.

I have the following directory structure for Ansible:

```
├── group-vars
│   └── kafka.yml
├── inventory
│   └── kafka
├── kafka.yml
└── roles
    └── kafka
        └── tasks
            ├── install.yml
            ├── main.yml
            └── verification.yml
```

**1. kafka.yml in group-vars**

```
software_dir: /home/sohanvir/softwares
kafka_installation_dir: "{{ software_dir }}/kafka"

kafka_version: kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0.tgz
kafka_download_link: "http://redrockdigimark.com/apachemirror/kafka/0.10.1.0/{{ kafka_version}}"
```

**2. inventory ==> kafka**

```
[kafka]
localhost
```

**3. Playbook==> kafka.yml**

```
- name: Install Kafka
  hosts: kafka
  connection: local
  roles:
    - kafka
```

**4. Role ==> kafka  ==> tasks**

**1. main.yml**

```
- include: verification.yml
- include: main.yml
```

**2. install.yml**

```
- name: Download kafka from link
  get_url:
    url: '{{ kafka_download_link }}'
    dest: '{{ kafka_installation_dir }}'

- name: Extract tar file
  shell: cd '{{ kafka_installation_dir }}' && tar -xzf '{{ kafka_2.11-0.10.1.0.tgz }}'
```

**3. verification.yml**

```
- name: Verify Directory Structure
  shell: mkdir -p '{{ kafka_installation_dir }}'
  ignore_errors: no
```

---

*I am running playbook using following command :*

```
 ansible-playbook -i inventory/kafka kafka.yml
```

But getting following error :

```
PLAY [Install Kafka] ***********************************************************
TASK [setup] ******************************************************************* ok: [localhost]
TASK [kafka : Verify Directory Structure] ************************************** fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "the field 'args' has an invalid value, which appears to include a variable that is undefined. The error was: 'kafka_installation_dir' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/home/sohanvir/personal_git/ansible/roles/kafka/tasks/verification.yml': line 1, column 3, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n- name: Verify Directory Structure\n ^ here\n"} to retry, use: --limit @/home/sohanvir/personal_git/ansible/kafka.retry
PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************* localhost : ok=1 changed=0 unreachable=0 failed=1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the directory name `group-vars` to `group_vars`.

See [Splitting Out Host and Group Specific Data](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_inventory.html#splitting-out-host-and-group-specific-data)'

Comment: And Here it goes : most stupid thing of the year :-) . Anyways  thanks a lot @techraf. It worked .